# How to get the Video duration from a Video tag created dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a way to get the video duration, without to have the video tag in the html ?

E.g:

```
var Video = $('<video></video>')
                            .append("<source src=video.mp4 type=video/mp4; codecs="+'"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'+ "/>")
                            .append("<source src=video.webm type=video/webm; codecs="+'"vp8, vorbis"'+ "/>");
```

I want to get the duration from "Video", is it possible?

Comment: I found this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221029/problem-retrieving-html5-video-duration

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/) to a good page on the video tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var vidElement = document.createElement('video');
$(vidElement).append("<source src=video.mp4 type=video/mp4; codecs="+'"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'+ "/>").append("<source src=video.webm type=video/webm; codecs="+'"vp8, vorbis"'+ "/>");

console.log(vidElement.duration);
```

So in that way you dont have the html in your page just in memory if that is what you want