# HTML5 Video duration without playing video

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to get video duration in HTML5 with out playing video or before playing video to show on video thumb as you seen on you tube or any other video sites.

Any help will be really appreciate.

Thanks  in Advance.

Comment: I think it is not always possible without starting the movie. I also suspect if youtube does it then they pre-process the movie on the server to get the duration.

Answer (score 31):

For HTML5 you should be able to use the video tag's duration property, once the file's metadata is loaded. See this answer for a good way to do it:

[Retrieving HTML5 video duration separately from the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221029/problem-retrieving-html5-video-duration#answer-2602558)

To quote the anwser by Mikushi:

```
myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log(videoPlayer.duration);
});
```

By listening for the 'loadedmetadata' event you will ensure the duration value has been loaded.

More details on the loadedmetadata can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp

**EDIT**

As per @lucas-vasques 's comment, instead of the `loadmetadata` event, you could use `durationchange` which the [MDN Media Events list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) describes as ...

> The metadata has loaded or changed, indicating a change in duration of
> the media.  This is sent, for example, when the media has loaded
> enough that the duration is known.

Comment: it is ok, but i would like to show on page load not any click event.

Comment: This is not an onclick event, this is when the video meta data loads (before any click events) more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp

Comment: +1, thanks for the helpful code. Shouldn't it be `myVideoPlayer` inside the callback instead of `videoPlayer` though?

Comment: +1, it works also where multiple versions of the same video are used in the same video element (as source elements).

Comment: There's an update: use `durationchange` instead of `loadedmetadata`

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDuration() {
            var s = document.getElementById('a');
            alert(s.duration)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <video src="2.mp4" id="a" controls="controls"></video>
    <button onclick="getDuration()">get duration</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special event triggered on video elements called "loadedmetadata". Once this one is triggered, properties such as duration are available on the video element.

Here's an exhaustive list of all HTML5 video events : http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assume "video" is the video node
var i = setInterval(function() {
    if(video.readyState > 0) {
        var minutes = parseInt(video.duration / 60, 10);
        var seconds = video.duration % 60;

        // (Put the minutes and seconds in the display)

        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 200);
```