# Cannot get video duration outside addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, variables, video, html5-video, duration

I have a function that logs the video duration into the console before the video is uploaded. However, I cannot get the video duration outside the `addEventListener` function because it returns back `NaN`. Despite of it, inside the function it successfully logs the proper video duration but if I save it into a variable it does not get the right value.
**Video duration function**

```
var duration = 0; // Set default variable for storing video duration
if(vfile.type == "video/webm" || vfile.type == "video/mp4" || vfile.type == "video/ogg" || vfile.type == "video/mov"){
        var video = document.createElement('video'); // Create video element
        video.preload = 'metadata'; // Set preload attribute to metadata
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
        video.addEventListener('durationchange', function() { // Check for duration
            console.log('Duration change', video.duration); // Successfully logs video duration into console e.g.: 13.012
            duration = video.duration; // Set duration variable to video.duration
        });
        console.log("Duration: ", duration); // Returns back 0
    }
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(vfile);
```

If I set variable `duration` to `video.duration` outside the `addEventListener` function it gives back `NaN`.
All in all, how could I set variable `duration` to the actual video duration for later usage in the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592009/html5-video-duration-without-playing-video

Comment: Some other issues unrelated to your question: you're setting `video.src` outside of the block of code that creates the video element. Also `revokeObjectURL` runs before `video.src` is set (and before the video is loaded), so it is effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning video.duration to duration in this code:

```
    video.addEventListener('durationchange', function() { // Check for duration
        console.log('Duration change', video.duration); // Successfully logs video duration into console e.g.: 13.012
        duration = video.duration; // Set duration variable to video.duration
    });
    console.log("Duration: ", duration); // Returns back 0
```

The problem is that `console.log("Duration: ", duration);` runs *before* `duration = video.duration;`, because `video.addEventListener` does not immediately run its function. If you do need to do something with the duration, you can run it after you assign the duration, like so:

```
    video.addEventListener('durationchange', function() { // Check for duration
        duration = video.duration; // Set duration variable to video.duration
        someOtherFunction();
    });
```

You could also use one of the other asynchronous data management techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6184972