# How can I get the duration of video with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Following code give me `undefined` message.

```
var video = $('<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>');
var source = $('<source>');
$(source).appendTo(video);
$(source).attr('src', 'php.mp4');
$(source).attr('type', 'video/mp4');
var d = $(video).duration;
console.log(d);
```

Comment: it won't give you duration until it loaded

Comment: Here is my new code sir, Please look into this                                                          var video = $('<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls preload="metadata">');      
   var source= $('<source>');
   $(source).append(video)
   $(source).attr('src','php.mp4');
   $(source).attr('type','video/mp4'); 
    $(video)[0].load();
   var d= $(video).duration
   alert(d);

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2602578/4161269

Comment: Thanks Bro, now it's working.....