# Trying to get full video duration but returning as Nan

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I am trying to get the video duration of my player but it returns `NaN`, I am not entirely sure how to access it from here.

```
<video id="videoPlayerNew" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-controls-enabled" poster="http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}" controls="">
    <source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">Javascript was disabled or not supported</p>
</video>

<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("videoPlayerNew");
    console.log(vid.duration);
</script>
```

The log tells me: `NaN`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem retrieving HTML5 video duration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221029/problem-retrieving-html5-video-duration)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Wait for [**`onloadedmetadata`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) event, The `loadedmetadata` event is fired when the **metadata** has been loaded.

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("videoPlayerNew");
myVideo.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  console.log('metadata loaded!');
  console.log(this.duration);//this refers to myVideo
};
```

```html
<video id="videoPlayerNew" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-controls-enabled" poster="http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}" controls="">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">Javascript was disabled or not supported</p>
</video>
```

Comment: for react users: <video onLoadedMetadata={onLoadedMetadata} />

Answer (score 3):

Try this code below, it adds the event after everything is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#videoPlayerNew").on( "timeupdate", function(event){
      console.log( this.duration);
    });
});
```